# How to store a Azure Pipeline Parameter which contains special characters to a variable in Bash

Tags: bash, azure-devops

I have been trying to store a azure devops pipeline parameter `${{ parameters.data }}` to a bash variable. The parameter contains data including loads of special characters which has been causing the `Bash@3` task to fail with exit code 2 as it interprets some of the data as commands.

I need the data inside `${{ parameters.data }}` to run a python script.

I have tried :

```
variable1 = '${{ parameters.data }}'
cp ${{ parameters.data }} $file
echo -n '${{ parameters.data }}' > $file
```

Nothing seems to work

Edit:
Azure Pipeline Definition

```
  - job: EmailResults
    displayName: Task1
    pool: ${{ parameters.pool }}
    steps:
      - task: Bash@3
        displayName: BashTask
        inputs:
          targetType: inline
          script: |
            filename="input.txt"
            echo -e "${{parameters.changeinfo}}" > "$filename"
            python3 ./file.py \
              --scan \
              --info $filename \
              --repo '${{ parameters.data1 }}'  \
              --project '${{ parameters.data2 }}'
```

Comment: What special characters do you use in parameters? Can you share a parameter value sample with us? This will be helpful to investigate the issue.

Comment: Sure. Some of them are `$, (), {}, '', #, |, ~, /, ;`

Comment: Can you share a complete parameter value sample? If possible, you can share more details about part of the Azure DevOps Pipeline definition.

Comment: I'm afraid i cant share the exact parameter value but i can share that its the output of `terraform plan`, hence contains special characters. I have edited the question with Azure Devops Pipeline definition.

Comment: From you pipeline definition, the issue exists in the command: `echo -e "${{parameters.changeinfo}}" > "$filename"` right? Can you share more error log info? This can help us locate the issue.

Comment: This is the output log                                                                                                                              /agent/_work/_temp/75fb73ea-5734-4ad0-97c6-e9ee02080165.sh: line 256: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/agent/_work/_temp/75fb73ea-5734-4ad0-97c6-e9ee02080165.sh: line 256: `          + "splunkAuthKey"                               = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=********;SecretName=**********)"'
##[error]Bash exited with code '2'. I have replaced sensitive data with *

Comment: I can reproduce the similar issue. You can try to use  quoted heredoc in bash to print the parameters value contains the special string to txt file.  Please check if it can work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your Yaml sample and error log, I can reproduce the similar issue when writing the parameter value to the txt file.

To solve this issue, you can change to use bash [quoted heredoc](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/bash-heredoc) to write the parameters value contains special characters to the txt file:

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      filename="input.txt"
      cat << 'EOT' > "$filename"
      ${{parameters.changeinfo}}
      EOT
      python3 ./file.py \
              --scan \
              --info $filename \
              --repo '${{ parameters.data1 }}'  \
              --project '${{ parameters.data2 }}'
```